# How to set initial focus on input field on page load (with VueJS 3 using Composition API)

Tags: input, vuejs3, setfocus, vue-composition-api

How can I set the focus on an HTML input field upon page loading while using the Composition API of VueJS 3?
I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" id="filter" v-model="filter">
</div>
```

And have tried this in the setup() function, but that doesn't set the focus:

```
setup() {
  onMounted(() => {
    const filter_fld = document.getElementById('filter')
    filter_fld.focus()
  })
}
```

I also tried using the below.
HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="text" ref="filter_fld" v-model="filter">
</div>
```

And in setup() function:

```
setup() {
  const filter_fld = ref(null)

  onMounted(() => {
    filter_fld.value?.focus()
  })
}
```

But also to no success unfortunately. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Have an input with a `ref` in your template e.g.:

```html
<input ref="filter" />
```

Then after component is mounted focus it by reference on next tick:

```js
import { ref, onMounted, nextTick } from 'vue';

setup() {
  const filter = ref(null);

  onMounted(() => {
    nextTick(() => {
      filter.value.focus();
    });
  });

  return {
    filter
  };
}
```

Comment: Hero!! Thanks a lot. Didn't know the nextTick() function.

Comment: This code is for vue2, not vue3 composition api?

Answer (score 5):

You can also use the `autofocus` native's HTML attribute:

```js
<input type = "text" id = "filter" v-model = "filter" autofocus/>
```

Comment: This only works when the page was loaded the first time. On the next succeeding loads, this will not work. This is Vue. Not native HTML.

Comment: It will work for a single web app with a single route. If your site has multiple routes, you might need to focus the form using the nextTick() function on a reload. Vue is a JS framework, it literally controls native HTML.